# setLayoutParams() returning null ptr

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an xml layout structure something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp">

    <TextView
       android:id="+@id/tv"
       ....
    />
</LinearLayout
```

I am trying to programatically increase the `marginRight` of the linear layout. In my Java code i have something like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0,0,100,0);

if(something is true){
  ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
else {
   //do nothing
}
```

I get an null ptr exception on the line `ll.setLayoutParams(lp);`

Comment: I doubt that your are getting a NPE. Probably you are getting a ClassCastException

Comment: Show more code where using `findViewById` make sure accessing views after setting layout for Activity in which LinearLayout with `ll` id

Answer (score 1):

"ll" has no parent, so you can't set margin to it, set padding instead, or set margin to the "tv"

Comment: yep this helps in doing what i want to achieve